# How to Get a Column number in Excel by its Column name

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, mvvm

I created an Excel application using C# with MVVM model. In that excel file I created some columns as **template columns**. For example I am having some columns like **Unit**, **Cost** and **Quantity**. Now I want to find the exact column number of "**Quantity**"  .

How can I get that particular column(Quantity) number?

Please can any one tell me some method to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Execute the Select statement and fill the dataset. Now traverse through the column in the table and find the index of column 'Quantity".

Sample code to load the excel file in Dataset:

public static DataSet exceldata(string filelocation)
    {

```
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    OleDbCommand excelCommand = new OleDbCommand(); OleDbDataAdapter excelDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();

    string excelConnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + filelocation + "; Extended Properties =Excel 8.0;Hdr=Yes";

    OleDbConnection excelConn = new OleDbConnection(excelConnStr);

    excelConn.Open();

    DataTable dtPatterns = new DataTable(); excelCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT `PATTERN` as PATTERN, `PLAN` as PLAN FROM [PATTERNS$] where 1=0", excelConn);

    excelDataAdapter.SelectCommand = excelCommand;

    excelDataAdapter.Fill(dtPatterns);

    "dtPatterns.TableName = Patterns";

    ds.Tables.Add(dtPatterns);

    return ds;

}
```

By using this method, you have loaded the table schema in dataset. Now you can store the column name and index in any of the collection variable and get the column index using the key column name in that collection.

Comment: Can you please send me the sample code for it? I didnt use dataset in my code I used IEnumurable Collection to store my data. Then how can i get it? Can you give me a bit more explanation about it?

Comment: @SuryaKavitha - What does _your_ code look like? How are you loading your data?

Comment: I am using IEnumurable local variable like "var TTLrecQtyList =  _taskPaneViewModel.TrackedItems ;" . In this TTLreqQtyList I am having all my Columns and its Values as well. Now I want a common method Which should accept My Column Name "Quantity" and it should return the corresponding column number.